# Ubuntu 18.04.5 Server DNS issue

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system

I am suddenly having a problem running updates on an Ubuntu 18.04.5 server after years of running weekly updates without any problems. It seems to be DNS related.

I am able to ping outside IP addresses but not FQDNs. I am able to connect to this machine from outside the network with SSH, so I know the connection is working.

systemd-resolve --status shows:

```
> Global
>          DNS Servers: 1.1.1.1
>                       1.0.0.1
>                       8.8.8.8
>           DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
>                       16.172.in-addr.arpa
>                       168.192.in-addr.arpa
>                       17.172.in-addr.arpa
>                       18.172.in-addr.arpa
>                       19.172.in-addr.arpa
>                       20.172.in-addr.arpa
>                       21.172.in-addr.arpa
>                       22.172.in-addr.arpa
>                       23.172.in-addr.arpa
>                       24.172.in-addr.arpa
>                       25.172.in-addr.arpa
>                       26.172.in-addr.arpa
>                       27.172.in-addr.arpa
>                       28.172.in-addr.arpa
>                       29.172.in-addr.arpa
>                       30.172.in-addr.arpa
>                       31.172.in-addr.arpa
>                       corp
>                       d.f.ip6.arpa
>                       home
>                       internal
>                       intranet
>                       lan
>                       local
>                       private
>                       test
> 
> Link 2 (eth0)
>       Current Scopes: none
>        LLMNR setting: yes MulticastDNS setting: no
>       DNSSEC setting: no
>     DNSSEC supported: no
```

I am stumped and would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: What is the content of the `/etc/resolv.conf` file?

Comment: nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 1.0.0.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8

Comment: Seems reasonable. So what happens if you try to ping a FQDN?

Comment: a good long delay of about 20 seconds and then ping: yahoo.com: Temporary failure in name resolution

Comment: Check your network connectivity and firewalls.

Comment: Network connectivity is fine as I am using SSH to connect to the server remotely. Turning off ufw does not help this issue. I am going to see if the network team made any changes on the network firewall.

Comment: Server settings ended up being fine. The network team made changes to Cisco Umbrella without informing me. Changed nameservers to the Umbrella DNS servers and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Server settings ended up being fine. The network team made changes to Cisco Umbrella without informing me. Changed nameservers to the Umbrella DNS servers and it is working now.